# VBS/Powershell Pinning a Custom Application to the Windows 7 Start Menu

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

I also had some success by using the `PinnedApplications` module for Powershell. Again I was able to pin Notepad, but not my custom EXE, probably because trying to pin to taskbar manually requires a `SHIFT+Right Click` on this app, whereas on notepad we can do this with just a `right-click`.

This leads me to believe that this is a step which needs to be overcome in the script as well - but how does one emulate a `shift + right click` in this context?

Powershell code:

```ps
Set-PinnedApplication -Action PinToStartMenu -FilePath "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"
```

---

Output from VBScript Run As Verbs:

```
open
run as admin
open with brackets 
troubleshoot compatibility
edit with notepad++
git init here
git bash
add to archive ...
add to "selfhelp.rar"
compress and email ...
compress to "selfhelp.rar" and email
scan with webroot
restore previous versions
_____ (blank entry, looks like this corresponds with 'Send To' action)
Cut
copy
create shortcut
delete
rename
properties
```

I have a custom app called `IT Self Help.EXE` which I would like to pin to user's start menu automatically using VBScript.

Using the code provided [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cd7d7a32-d214-4fbe-8e1c-e0cc7b69d172/add-desired-icons-to-taskbar-and-start-menu-using-scripts?forum=w7itproui), I was able to pin notepad to the start menu (where notepad.exe is saved in system32):

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  'Declare constants
Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17 
Const CSIDL_PROGRAMS = &H2

strNotepadIcon = "notepad.exe"

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\windows\system32")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strNotepadIcon) 
Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs 
For Each objVerb in colVerbs 
    If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Start Menu" Then objVerb.DoIt 
Next
```

However, if I save a copy of IT Self Help into System32, and run the following the script is completely unresponsive (no error and no pinning):

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'Declare constants
Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17 
Const CSIDL_PROGRAMS = &H2

strNotepadIcon = "IT Self Help.exe"

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\windows\system32")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strNotepadIcon) 
Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs 
For Each objVerb in colVerbs 
    If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Start Menu" Then
    objVerb.DoIt 
Next
```

Can anyone provide any tips as to why this may not work?

I have read that this type of access has been deliberately removed from Windows, but I can't seem to find any more information on it:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx

Does anyone know what exactly is preventing me from adding IT Self Help where Notepad can be added without issue?

Comment: Maybe try enumerating the `colVerbs` and outputting them to see what Verbs are available to `IT Self Help.exe`?

Comment: This maybe a worthwhile read [Verbs and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Out of interest what happens if you right click on the `IT Self Help.exe` in the File Explorer do you see `Pin to Start Menu`? Mine for example shows `Pin to Start` but I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: After running my own tests I would say the answer is because the `Verb` doesn't appear to exists on some executables. There maybe some extra steps required to make the `Verb` appear.

Comment: Hi Lankymart, thanks for the various comments. When I right-click the IT Help app, there is no "pin to start" option, but this does appear after holding left shit and then right-clicking. I'm not sure if there is perhaps a way to emulate this 'shift-rightclick'. Also added a powershell script to my question for reference

Comment: Some more really useful info including clarification of the SHIFT behaviour you describe, they are called "Extended Verbs". See [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx). There is also [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110411-00/?p=10973), which suggests that "Pin to Start" is not designed for programs, so that got me thinking...have you tried creating a shortcut to the `exe` then checking the `Verbs` for that?

Comment: Scrap that just tried a shortcut without success.

Comment: I modified the script to quickly output all the Verbs just add `Wscript.Echo "Verb: " & Replace(objVerb.Name & "", "&", "")` to the `For Each`. Notice that some `Verb: ` outputs are blank but when comparing with the context menu right click looks like one of the blanks corresponds to `Pin to Start` in terms of location.

Comment: Hi Lankymart, I did notice that, but I can't seem to work out how to 'activate' these blank verbs. Also, I am only seeing one blank entry, and it corresponds with the "Send To"  verb (which is a dropdown). It definitely seems that Microsoft doesn't want us doing this!

Comment: Interesting when I test a `.lnk` I get 5 blanks but when I test a `.exe` I get 4 blanks with one of them corresponding to the position of `Pin to Start` on the context menu. I am using Windows 8.1 however so maybe differences. You could try changing the `For Each` to a `For` and iterating over the collection the `FolderItemVerbs` collection has a [`Item()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774162(v=vs.85).aspx) that accepts an index ordinal.

Comment: Ah, it must be a Windows 8 / Windows 7 distinction then, when I try the same (checking the verbs for a shortcut file) there is still only 1 blank (send to), and no sign of pin to start - perhaps a question for Super Users - 'How to allow custom app to pin to start menu?'

Comment: I'll continue to dig...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this feature is only available for applications which have been installed on the machine.

As my application is a standalone exe without any installation, I don't think this is possible unless I package it into an installer